# web3 1.0.0-beta example for etherscan websocket?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, infura, web3-providers

Does anyone have a working JS example for wss://socket.etherscan.io/wshandler?

Or any alternative websocket providers, besides Infura?

The reason I'm looking for Infura alternatives is it fails for me in two ways that are pretty much blockers:

1) it doesn't implement ping/pong and therefore I get random disconnects. I haven't found a bulletproof workaround, though I tried 
a) subscribing for new blocks 
b) calling contract immutable methods periodically

2) there seems to be a problem with larger chunks of data when e.g. calling `getPastEvents` to fetch blocks with a big number of transactions consistently result in disconnect with `Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node on IPC.` I don't know if this is Infura's fault or e.g. websocket or else - but I thought maybe I start by testing a different provider. Any other debugging suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a fix or alternative to infura? I'm having the exact same issue with the websocket

Comment: Nope nothing yet..

Comment: My current work around is using the onError reconnect code provided by 7Ds7 here https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1354